# Angular js filter Query - show a value if no matches found

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a query filter set up

and a filter set up

I am using country as an example.  It could be anything including cities, names, animals etc.   This what I want to do.  I am using this filter to select one item from a very large array (5000 + records) If my query filter has no matches  that are found I would like to show "Not Found / Other" as one of the selections.  How do I go about it?  I don't want to set this value to default.  But show only if nothing else if found.

Comment: Why not write a function that processes the result you need? I have seen this http://codepen.io/PageOnline/pen/nCfAj  before. If you post some code you might get more help.

Comment: Google Angular Customer Filter, it will give you some idea how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-show` directive to display your required option when your query returns no matches.

**html**

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="country"/><br>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in filteredCountries = (countries | filter:country)">{{c.name}}</li>
    <li ng-show="!filteredCountries.length">Not Found / Other</li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.countries = [
    {name:'US'},
    {name:'UK'},
    {name:'Brazil'},
    {name:'Chile'},
    {name:'India'}
  ];

}
```

Here is a working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ArnVCO?p=preview).

Comment: I will accept this as an answer to the question I had asked.  I am trying to do something similar in Ionic which uses Angular JS.  Below is my html.  It didn't work for me.  My array is populated with a restful api.   <div class="list" ng-model="merchmodalData.merchant">
            <ion-radio  ng-repeat="item in merchants  | filter:query | limitTo:10" ng-click="doSomething(item)"> </ion-radio>
                 <ion-radio ng-show="!merchants.length" >Not Found / Other</ion-radio>                                             
              {{item.name}}
          </div>